# C++98/C++03 STL set bug?

Tags: c++, stl, set

all,

One weird thing happens when I'm using set:
Let's say:

```
struct A {
  int num;
  bool operator<(const A& x) const
  {
    return num < x.num;
  }
};

struct B {
  set<A> ASet;
};

struct C {
  list<B> BList;
  list<B>::iterator BListIter;
  C()
  {
    BList.push_back(B());
    BListIter = --(BList.end());
  }
};
```

somewhere we can have this code:

```
list<C> CList;
CList.push_back(C());
list<C>::iterator CListIter = --(CList.end());
for (...) {
  A a = ...;
  ...
  CListIter->BListIter->ASet.insert(a);
```

this will end up with segmentation fault after a few iterations. When this happens, I found an invalid item is referenced and compared (its address is 0x0000001b, so definitely wrong) during the insertion.

Funny thing is when I turn on -std=c++0x this option to use C++11 the problem goes aways! So I wonder if this is a bug of STL set in C++98/C++03?

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: There must be something more going on in the code you didn't show. Are you modifying `ASet` or `BList` inside the `for` loop? Please post a more complete listing. Also note that using `BList.back()` is a better way to access the last element.

Comment: Present a complete, compileable example which demonstrates the problem.  Just because a problem appears to go away using different settings, does not mean that the compiler or library was doing anything wrong in the other setting. It could mean (more than likely does mean), that your code has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++03 or earlier, copies of the temporary objects are put on `CList` and the `BList` inside the `CList` object.

When the `C::BList` member is copied, a completely new `list<B>` is created, but when the `C::BListIter` member is copied, the new `C::BListIter` iterator still refers to the `C::BList` list in the original `C` object - which is a temporary that gets destroyed.  So that iterator refers to an element of a destroyed list.

In C++11 move constructors are used instead of copy constructors, so the resulting iterator doesn't refer to a dead object.